# View Controller open from AppDelegate (from Universal Link) don't have the navigation controller

Tags: ios, swift

I created a universal link for an app. It works great. It opens the app and goes to the view controller defined and it shows the correct info passed through the universal link. The problem is that the view controller has a navigation controller. But when I access directly from appdelegate, it doesn't show this navigation controller.

How I can define the present in AppDelegate to show the view controller with the navigation controller?

```
if let controller = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "AnuncioV2ViewController") as? AnuncioV2ViewController {
    if let window = self.window, let rootViewController = window.rootViewController {
        var currentController = rootViewController
        while let presentedController = currentController.presentedViewController {
            currentController = presentedController
        }
        controller.idAd = adID
        controller.id_usuario = self.userID
        controller.anuncio = anuncio as! [String:Any]

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            currentController.present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In the future, formatting your code so that it's readable like code on this website is a big help to us.

Comment: Sorry for that, all code was formatting, but i don know why just a part shows correctly.

Comment: It's cool. Each line of code just needs four spaces in front of it to work. The reason that section worked automatically was because it was probably already indented by four spaces like Xcode does automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless `AnuncioV2ViewController` is a subclass of `UINavigationController`, you're literally just leaving out a step. If it's all set up correctly in your storyboard, just provide the parent navigation controller an identifier and instantiate that instead. You can then access the `AnuncioV2ViewController` instance by using `navigationController.children.first! as! AnuncioV2ViewController`. (If this is in your storyboard and this works at least once correctly, those force-unwraps should be fine for prime-time.)

Comment: Work Perfect! Thanks!!